# exim4 checking client certificates always invalid

Tags: debian, configuration, certificate, exim, tls

My exim server is configured to ask for a client certificates when a connection is made. I set up an ACL (at rcpt stage) to log or add a header resp. of the outcome of the certificate check:

```
warn
   encrypted = *
   ! verify = certificate
   #condition = ${if def:tls_in_peerdn {yes}{no}}   # -> newer versions of exim use $tls_in_peerdn!
   condition = ${if def:tls_peerdn {yes}{no}} 
   add_header = X-TLS-Client-Certificate: invalid (${tls_peerdn})
   log_message = Invalid TLS client certificate presented (${tls_peerdn}).

warn
   encrypted = *
   ! verify = certificate
   condition = ${if def:tls_peerdn {no}{yes}} 
  log_message = No TLS client certificate presented.

warn
   verify = certificate  
   add_header = X-TLS-Client-Certificate: valid
   condition = false
```

Unfortunately no message I see ever gets checked as valid. The check for no certificate works though.

I set up

```
tls_try_verify_hosts = *
```

So the checking takes place and (using Debian, it is included in the standard config) the trust anchors are configured and accessible:

```
tls_verify_certificates = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Testing with...

```
openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -verify 4 -connect mailserver.dom.tld:25 -starttls smtp -cert /etc/ssl/letsencrypt/fullchain.pem -key /etc/ssl/letsencrypt/privkey.pem
```

...from the server to itself using the same key as the server uses, including the intermediate certs in the right order doesn't give a valid check result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for parameter -CAfile should be your Let's encrypt's chain.pem and the value for -cert cert.pem:

```
openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/ssl/letsencrypt/chain.pem -verify 4 \
        -connect mailserver.dom.tld:25 -starttls smtp \
        -cert /etc/ssl/letsencrypt/cert.pem \
        -key /etc/ssl/letsencrypt/privkey.pem
```

Like this your certificate will be validated by your server.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is using the default configuration, it should be using the `snakeoil` self-signed certificate.  This is adequate and acceptable to establish TLS connections on outgoing and incoming connections.  It will however fail validation.  You will need to use a certificate from a trusted authority to pass validation.

Are you providing clients with certificates that they can use in place of a login?  Other than your users provided with user certificates, I would expect client certificates to fail frequently.  Many servers use a self-signed certificate, or have other issues that will cause validation failures.

Exim won't ask for a client certificate unless you set `tls_verify_hosts` or `tls_try_verify_hosts`.  Certificate are well covered in the [Encrypted SMTP connections](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-encrypted_smtp_connections_using_tlsssl.html) section of the Exim documentation.

Many organizations have trouble getting their DNS correctly configured for STMP usage.  DKIM is particularly troublesome, and most signers I encounter fail validation.  I have little hope that many sites have configured their servers with the correct valid certificates.

After recent restricting connections to TLS v1.0 and above, I have had to stop announcing `STARTTLS` to a number of servers. I haven't yet resorted to trying to validate TLS certificates for any clients.  If I ever do, it would at most count towards their spam score.  I may enable the `tls_peerdn` log selector to investigate if any sites could pass validation.

SMTP over TLS is growing but far from the standard.  Those sites that do use it are sites that are well-trusted by other means.

UPDATE: I've checked my logs, and so far only two senders have passed validation.  Most clients didn't validate.

I tried validating my certificate:

- OpenSSL connects as `openssl.client.net` which shouldn't pass rDNS valiation.
- The fullchain.cert doesn't trace back to a cert in the default trust store.  This is OK as the chain cert is signed by a certificate in the trust store.
- It appears openssl doesn't even try to send the client certificate. Possibly because of the trust chain. It might work if you added the third certificate to the fullchain.pem file.
- I see the DN of the server listed, but no indication that open_ssl even tried to send the certificate.

The test command I used was:

```
echo quit | openssl s_client -cert fullchain.pem -key privkey.pem \
   -starttls smtp -connect mail.systemajik.com:587 -debug 2>&1 | less
```

Comment: The server uses let's encrypt certs. But it's not my certificates that do fail, it's those that get presented to my server upon asking them to do so. And it is not for AUTH, it's just to check the identity of the connecting MTA. Yesterday I saw some mail coming from Gmail, that passed the check, so I suppose it is not my config, doing it wrong. Still I wonder, why I can't connect to my server with its own cert and privkey using s_client without failing the check...

Comment: @AdrianZaugg I've added updates.